# Git 1.9 remote push -u changes

Tags: git, git-branch

I just upgraded from 1.8.4.3 to 1.9.1, and I'm noticing a changed behavior.

In 1.8.4.3 when I would `git checkout -b new_branch`, and `git push -u origin new_branch`, 1.8.4.3 would create a new branch in the remote named `origin`.

In 1.9 it just says `Branch git_1.9_test_branch set up to track remote branch master from origin by rebasing.`

Why is this? How can I have 1.9 also create the branch on my remote named `origin` in a similar fashion to 1.8? If I don't do this, when I `git push`, my changes get pushed to the branch I branched off of (in this case `master`) which is obviously undesired.

An example below:

```
# 1.8.4.3
$ git checkout -b new_branch
Branch git_1.9_test_branch set up to track local branch master_newui by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'git_1.9_test_branch'

$ git push origin -u new_branch
Counting objects: 24, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (6/6), done.
Writing objects: 100% (6/6), 1.41 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 6 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
To git@github.com:myorg/myrepo.com.git
 * [new branch]      new_branch -> new_branch
Branch new_branch set up to track remote branch new_branch from origin by rebasing.



# 1.9.1
$ git co -b new_branch
Branch new_branch set up to track local branch master_newui by rebasing.
Switched to a new branch 'new_branch'

$ git push -u origin new_branch
Branch new_branch set up to track remote branch master_newui from origin by rebasing.
Everything up-to-date
```

My global git config has

```
[push]
  default = upstream
```

Comment: The question is not clear. That's how 1.9.x works.

Comment: @zerkms i have updated the question with more clarifications -- the issue is that when I `git push -u origin new_branch` no new branch is created on the remote.  So, when I push an actual commit, it ends up being pushed to the branch I branched from (master) instead of `new_branch`

Comment: Your shell-dump is not reflecting what you're wondering about - as i read this both tells me the same. While the 1.9-protocol does not show the network-transfer, but that may depend on changes about console handling. Did you try to make a --verbose push?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fix was to change my global `.gitconfig` file.

I had to update this:

```
[push]
  default = upstream
```

To this:

```
[push]
  default = simple
```